# How to run each loop on single item?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm pulling all associated objects of a particular object, and doing an `each_with_index` on it.

ie. `subscription.transactions.each_with_index`

But when there is only one `transaction` (and thus it's not an array), I get an `undefined method 'each'` error.

How do I get around this and basically just run the `each` once?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do

```
Array(subscription.transactions).each_with_index
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this

```
[subscription.transactions].flatten.each_with_index
```